# I am getting a NoSuchKey error when moving json files into DynamoDB from S3 and can't resolve

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a Lambda trigger set up when a new file is dropped into my S3 bucket.  I am trying to use that event to trigger a transfer of GEOjson files into DynamoDB.  Here is my code.

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader, parse_float=Decimal)
    table = dynamodb.Table('he_geojson_db1')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
```

Here are the errors:

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

I am new to boto3 (and AWS in general).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `print(event)`?

Comment: @Marcin it came out with this.

"errorMessage": "'Records'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']\n"